# What is the subject of the "Got me..." lines in Iron Maiden's song "Prowler"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech, lyrics

I'm trying to understand more in depth / translate some Iron Maiden songs, and this is something that has bugged me since the first time I listened to "Prowler".

Here are the lyrics of the song I'm talking about:

> Walking through the city, looking oh so pretty
>   I've just got to find my way
>   See the ladies flashing, all their legs and lashes
>   I've just got to find my way
>   Well you see me crawling through the bushes with it open wide
>   What you seeing girl?
>   Can't you believe that feeling, can't you believe it
>   Can't you believe your eyes?
>   It's the real thing girl
>   Got me feeling myself and reeling around
>   Got me talking but feel like walking around
>   Got me feeling myself and reeling a-
>   Got me talking but nothing's with me
>   Got me feeling myself and reeling around

My question is: what is the meaning of the "Got me..." lines?
I would think it is "You, girl, got me while I...", but then there's this line:

> Got me talking but feel like walking around

How can it be paraphrased? Is the subject of "Got me" and "feel" the same? Could "Got me..." mean "I found myself..."?

Comment: I think that we can talk about the construction "(you) got me..." without going too deep into the sexual innuendo in the overall lyric. There's a similar usage in the Kink's lyrics http://www.metrolyrics.com/you-really-got-me-lyrics-kinks.html (Girl, you really got me goin'/You got me so I don't know what I'm doin')

Comment: So you assume the subject to be (you), right? So, the line with "feel like" is just an impromptu change of subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the line as follows:
(You) Got me talking but (I) feel like walking around

I agree with your comment that all the 'Got me' lines have the implicit subject of (you) referring to the girl mentioned in previous lines. There appears to be a sudden change in subject following the word 'but' only in that specific line.